# Electrical power requirements for Starship or Falcon 9

Tags: spacex, falcon-9, power, spacex-starship, battery

Anybody know where one could dig up electrical requirements for Starship? In other words, if Starship were sitting on the launch pad drawing power prior to launch, what would the load be?

I imagine that at least one requirement is for recharging Tesla EV-like batteries, and from looking at specs for Supercharger it seems to be 480vdc... but I've no idea of the amps.

This is for a "shore" power concept, albeit for a lunar environment. Any help is greatly appreciated. If anyone has a similar example with another launcher, I'm all ears.